# Is there a limited number of items for list in react-admin?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I'm using a List from react-admin and my data was limited to 100 items.
I don't need pagination and i'm sure i'm recieving more then 100 items in my list but in MyComponent  i only this 100 items. There is a limit for lists ?

```
<List title="welcome" filters={<CustomFilter />} pagination={null} {...props} >
        <MyComponent />
</List>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `perPage` prop? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#records-per-page

Comment: Yes i tried with perPage=1000 but i got only 100 items.

Comment: I found the issue, is referenced in another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607492/bad-fetch-in-react-admin-list-component-with-custom-iterator